# Quickest way to print lines diagonally given a list of lists:

Tags: python, algorithm

I was studying for a interview when I came across this question.

Given a list of lists which looks like this as a matrix:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

The output should be

```
1 4 2 7 5 3 8 6 9
```

Basically, given a list of lists in Python, print the lines diagonally. What would be the most pythonic way to accomplish this? I have looked over some C code and for loops but is there a better way?

Comment: "What would be the most pythonic way to accomplish this?" Probably with some Python code! What have you tried and what didn't work in your attempt?

Comment: Studying involves actually practicing things on your own. Asking us to solve the problem for you is not practice, it's "I'm lazy and can't be bothered to learn anything". YOU write some code, we'll MAYBE try to help fix it.

Comment: Literally every single one of your posts is of this type. The only one that isn't closed, you happened to have a problem with a feature that's built into the language that does it for you. Please be more considerate to those who volunteer their time to help people and show the effort you've already put into these problems. I'm not trying to be mean, but this is a habitual problem of yours. =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> a = numpy.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
>>> reduce(operator.add,(list(a[::-1].diagonal(i)) for i in range(-len(a),len(a)
)))
[1, 4, 2, 7, 5, 3, 8, 6, 9]
```

might be faster ... (doubt it .. but its cooler :P)